# In AIX copy only the permissions from one directory(A) to another directory(B)

Tags: permissions, file-permissions, aix

So on an AIX server. I have a directory with 100s of files and sub-directories... that I need to copy just the permissions, (not over write the files) to another directory

So need to Copy directory(A) permissions to directory(B)

I have had no success of finding a way to perform this on AIX.

Comment: Not a complete solution but you will want to use aclget and aclput along with a find.  I currently don't have access to an AIX system (I'm on vacation) so I can provide a detailed example.  Also, if you have a file in A called dog that is not in B, what do you want to do?  And vice verssa.  If a file in B is not in A, what permissions should it get?

Comment: Looks like to use aclget or aclput... one would need sudo/root access. I'm afraid i can't use this means... thanks for the reply though

Answer (score 1):

If the user owns the file, then aclget and aclput can be used.  Here is an example of changing b/foo to have the same permissions as a/foo.  guest owns the two foo files but ownership of the containing directory is not necessary:

```
# ls -ld * */*
drwxr-xr-x    2 root     system          256 Mar 06 17:25 a
-rwxrwxrwx    1 guest    system            0 Mar 06 17:25 a/foo
drwxr-xr-x    2 root     system          256 Mar 06 17:25 b
----------    1 guest    system            0 Mar 06 17:25 b/foo

# su - guest

$ id
uid=100(guest) gid=100(usr)
$ aclget a/foo | aclput b/foo
$ ls -ld * */*
drwxr-xr-x    2 root     system          256 Mar 06 17:25 a
-rwxrwxrwx    1 guest    system            0 Mar 06 17:25 a/foo
drwxr-xr-x    2 root     system          256 Mar 06 17:25 b
-rwxrwxrwx    1 guest    system            0 Mar 06 17:25 b/foo
```

If the user does not own the files, then he can not change the permissions with chmod or aclput